# Monodroid with Visual Studios Pro 2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010

I know the basics of the integration of the plugins and have done this before but lately I keep getting basic errors.

This time I don't even get a error the emulator is up and I can see it in running devices and it even deployed to the AndroidVM (my emulator name). Also saying it was a success and nothing happens and it was never installed on the device.

Answer (score -1):

You can't deploy monodroid based apps to your device unless you've the full version of MonoDroid tools

Comment: i know that, Notice in the Question where it Says Emulator.